# Confusion on enclosed area

Tags: contest-math, graphing-functions, area, absolute-value

> **1987 AIME, Problem #4**
>
> Find the area of the region enclosed by the graph of $|x − 60| + |y| = |x/4|$.

My attempt:

We have
\begin{equation}
|y|=|x/4|-|x-60| = \begin{cases}-\frac{3x}{4}+60, &\text{if $x\ge60$}. \\ \frac{5x}{4}-60, &\text{if $60>x\ge0$}. \\ \frac{3x}{4}-60, &\text{if $0>x$}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Clearly these are really only 4 cases because of the symmetry of the signs of the first and third cases, and our equations eventually turn out to be
\begin{equation}
y = -3x + 60 \\ y = \frac{3}{4}x-60 \\ y=\frac{5}{4}x-60 \\ y = -\frac{5}{4}x+60
\end{equation}
If we plot these lines, we have in the area enclosed by all of these lines, a concave shape which can be described as a triangle cut out from a larger triangle. However, if we just plot the equation of the original problem statement, it is only a quadrilateral that is a smaller enclosure which is plotted. What did I do wrong?

Comment: All seems fine, [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs%28x-60%29%2Babs%28y%29%3Dabs%28x%2F4%29%2C+y%3D-3%2F4*x%2B60%2C+y%3D3%2F4*x-60%2C+y%3D-5%2F4*x%2B60%2C+y%3D5%2F4*x-60) plot.

Comment: Remove the last four terms and you will see what I mean. In other words, just plot the absolute value equation. You may also wish to use Desmos instead; it's much faster and shows the LaTeX.

Comment: No, I don't see what you mean. [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7By%3C%3D-3%2F4*x%2B60%2C+y%3E%3D3%2F4*x-60%2C+y%3E%3D-5%2F4*x%2B60%2C+y%3C%3D5%2F4*x-60%7D)?

Comment: Like this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4u9c4cnank